# Manually set QGIS vertex coordinate in lat-long format

Tags: qgis, latitude-longitude

I'm new to QGIS (and GIS in general)

I'm creating a map and would like to manually enter lat-long coordinates in decimal format.

[image: vertex editor]

As you can see, the vertex editor uses a different coordinate system (I assume it's metres) but I'd like to set coordinates in decimal format, just like the bottom right of the photo

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a list of coordinates, put them into a csv and then load the csv.

If you have to do it "on the fly", create a new layer with a degree based coordinate reference system (CSR), e.g. WGS 84 (EPSG-code 4326).

Out of couriosity: Why do you want to enter the coordinates manually and one by one?

Comment: Any way to convert the existing layer to decimal format?

Comment: and it's just a small handful of coordinates i'd like to set by hand

Comment: There's the possibility to set the CRS when saving a layer to a new location.

Comment: Awesome thanks, you can add that as another answer or include it into your current one. It helped